# R transforms column to NA value - why?

Tags: r, file-io, na, csv

I want to read in tab delimited files with one column indicating a class denoted by a "roman" enumeration (each file contains either i,ii,iii or iv in the second column). However, with files containing only "i", this column is transformed to NA values. I can reproduce this error with a small test file looking like this:

```
animal  class   info
dog i   a
cat i   a
rabbit  i   b
```

When I read it into R:

```
> d<-read.delim("test_roman.csv", sep="\t")
> d
  animal class info
1    dog    NA    a
2    cat    NA    a
3 rabbit    NA    b
```

What am I missing here? `read.delim` always worked for me on similar files.

Comment: I edited the question to make that point clearer. I have different files, each containing only either `i` , `ìi`...they are loaded in R and then combined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have found out if you had visualized the type:

```
typeof(d$class)
[1] "complex"
```

You clearly don't want to have a complex number, so we enforce the "character" class:

```
read.table("test_roman.csv", sep="\t", fill=T, colClasses="character", header=T)
# animal  class   info
# dog     i       a
# cat     i       a
# rabbit  i       b
```

If your file contains not only *i* but also *ii* and *iv*, it works nonetheless:

```
read.delim("test_roman2.csv", sep="\t")
#   animal class info
#1     dog     i    a
#2     cat     i    a
#3 rabbit      i    b
#4 rabbit     iv    b
#5 rabbit     ii    b
```

Comment: I would have thought so too, but if there are other values in the "class" column, shouldn't that column automatically be detected as character or factor?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes, indeed, then it works, as shown in my update.

Comment: Have not thought of that! I was looking if there might be an escape sequence hiding in `\ti`. Thanks a lot! But one question remains: What can I do if I have a numerical 4th column I want to use for calculations? It will now also be a character. Do I have to transform it after the readin or is there an easier solution?

Comment: @aldorado Then use `colClasses=c(rep("character",3), "numeric")`. I would then use a full specification of your data set.

Comment: Concerning the minimal example: Different tab delimited files are created before they are loaded in R and combined. So the error can happen.